# Different resource description from Kubernetes Dashboard and kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-cronjob

I'm running a small AKS Kubernetes cluster on version 1.24 that needs to be upgraded to 1.25 soon. We are using terraform to provision resources like cronjobs etc. More precisely, cronjobs are created through the terraform resouce `kubernetes_cron_job`.

Because of the removal of `apiVersion: batch/v1beta1` in Kubernetes 1.25, we want to switch to the resource `kubernetes_cron_job_v1`.

The problem I currently have is that there seems to be a difference between the resource description in `kubectl` and the Kubernetes Dashboard.

**kubectl get cronjob cronjob-name -o yaml:**

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "..."
  generation: 1
  name: ...
  namespace: ...
  resourceVersion: "..."
  uid: ...
spec:
  concurrencyPolicy: Replace
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
    spec:
      backoffLimit: 2
      completions: 1
      manualSelector: false
      parallelism: 1
      template:
        metadata:
          creationTimestamp: null
        spec:
          automountServiceAccountToken: true
          containers:
          - command:
            - ...
            - ...
            image: ...
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            name: tms-api
            resources: {}
            terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
            terminationMessagePolicy: File
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /etc/secrets
              mountPropagation: None
              name: secrets
              readOnly: true
          dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
          enableServiceLinks: true
          restartPolicy: Never
          schedulerName: default-scheduler
          securityContext: {}
          shareProcessNamespace: false
          terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
          volumes:
          - name: secrets
            secret:
              defaultMode: 256
              optional: false
              secretName: ...
      ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 10
  schedule: 35 * * * *
  startingDeadlineSeconds: 10
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  suspend: false
status:
  lastScheduleTime: "..."
  lastSuccessfulTime: "..."
```

**Kubernetes Dashboard:**

```
kind: CronJob
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: ...
  namespace: ...
  uid: ...
  resourceVersion: '...'
  generation: 1
  creationTimestamp: '...'
  managedFields:
    - manager: HashiCorp
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: batch/v1
      time: '...'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:spec:
          f:concurrencyPolicy: {}
          f:failedJobsHistoryLimit: {}
          f:jobTemplate:
            f:spec:
              f:backoffLimit: {}
              f:completions: {}
              f:manualSelector: {}
              f:parallelism: {}
              f:template:
                f:spec:
                  f:automountServiceAccountToken: {}
                  f:containers:
                    k:{"name":"tms-api"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:command: {}
                      f:image: {}
                      f:imagePullPolicy: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:resources: {}
                      f:terminationMessagePath: {}
                      f:terminationMessagePolicy: {}
                      f:volumeMounts:
                        .: {}
                        k:{"mountPath":"/etc/secrets"}:
                          .: {}
                          f:mountPath: {}
                          f:mountPropagation: {}
                          f:name: {}
                          f:readOnly: {}
                  f:dnsPolicy: {}
                  f:enableServiceLinks: {}
                  f:restartPolicy: {}
                  f:schedulerName: {}
                  f:securityContext: {}
                  f:shareProcessNamespace: {}
                  f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {}
                  f:volumes:
                    .: {}
                    k:{"name":"secrets"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:secret:
                        .: {}
                        f:defaultMode: {}
                        f:optional: {}
                        f:secretName: {}
              f:ttlSecondsAfterFinished: {}
          f:schedule: {}
          f:startingDeadlineSeconds: {}
          f:successfulJobsHistoryLimit: {}
          f:suspend: {}
    - manager: kube-controller-manager
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: batch/v1
      time: '2024-01-02T09:35:06Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:status:
          f:lastScheduleTime: {}
          f:lastSuccessfulTime: {}
      subresource: status
spec:
  schedule: 35 * * * *
  startingDeadlineSeconds: 10
  concurrencyPolicy: Replace
  suspend: false
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
    spec:
      parallelism: 1
      completions: 1
      backoffLimit: 2
      manualSelector: false
      template:
        metadata:
          creationTimestamp: null
        spec:
          volumes:
            - name: secrets
              secret:
                secretName: ...
                defaultMode: 256
                optional: false
          containers:
            - name: tms-api
              image: >-
                ...
              command:
                - ...
              resources: {}
              volumeMounts:
                - name: secrets
                  readOnly: true
                  mountPath: /etc/secrets
                  mountPropagation: None
              terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
              terminationMessagePolicy: File
              imagePullPolicy: Always
          restartPolicy: Never
          terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
          dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
          automountServiceAccountToken: true
          shareProcessNamespace: false
          securityContext: {}
          schedulerName: default-scheduler
          enableServiceLinks: true
      ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 10
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
status:
  lastScheduleTime: '...'
  lastSuccessfulTime: '...'
```

In the output from Kubernetes Dashboard, the main `apiVersion` is still `batch/v1beta1`. In the `kubectl` output, the job is on `batch/v1`.

To make it a little bit more confusing : When inspecting a cronjob not yet migrated to `kubernetes_cron_job_v1`, everything seems already to be ok :

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
...
```

I don't want to launch a Kubernetes upgrade as long as the output seems to be contradictory. So I'm wondering, which version here is correct.

I'm using the following versions:

```
$ terraform --version
Terraform v1.6.6
on linux_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v3.85.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubernetes v2.24.0
```

Any hints or insights into this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks and best regards,

Pascal

**EDIT:** Output of `kubectl api-resources --api-group=batch` :

```
NAME       SHORTNAMES   APIVERSION   NAMESPACED   KIND
cronjobs   cj           batch/v1     true         CronJob
jobs                    batch/v1     true         Job
```

Comment: Can you please add to the question output of `kubectl api-resources --api-group=batch`

Comment: @SaifeddineRajhi added to the original message. Thanks for the help!

Comment: very weird behaviour from the `dashboard` .. what happens when you change to`kubernetes_cron_job_v1` in your terraform code and run plan ? is it trying to delete/update this resouce ?

Comment: @SaifeddineRajhi When only changing the resource type, but not the name, it does : `Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.` Although I need to apply it twice because of `cronjobs.batch "name" already exists`.

In the end, whether I change the name or not, the Dashboard shows the same result.


Given the output of `kubectl api-resources`, how can it be there is anything on `batch/v1beta1` at all?

Comment: I maybe know why .. what is output of `kubectl version --short` if it is higher than 1.25 then that's why in kubectl you see `batch/v1` :D

Comment: @SaifeddineRajhi that was one of the first things I checked ;D

```$ kubectl version
Client Version: v1.28.2
Kustomize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
Server Version: v1.24.10
WARNING: version difference between client (1.28) and server (1.24) exceeds the supported minor version skew of +/-1```
I guess the version of kubectl shouldn't influence the output..?

Comment: It does of course

Comment: I have suggestion it might work, try to to run terraform import the cronjob `Terraform import xxx.kubernetes_cron_job_v1.name namespace/name`

Comment: @SaifeddineRajhi I downgraded kubectl to 1.24. No changes. Also downgraded Kubernetes Dashboard to 2.6.1 instead of 2.7.0, to guarantee compatibility with 1.24. I'll take a look at the terraform import

Comment: check [this article](https://medium.com/doctrine/upgrading-eks-to-1-25-1b8b14187a05)

Comment: @SaifeddineRajhi it seems to be entirely a Kubernetes Dashboard problem... I found some monitoring on AKS, through which I can find usages of deprecated Kubernetes APIs. Switching to the v1 cronjobs removes the deprecated APIs, despite the Dashboard showing otherwise. I didn't identify the dashboard problem yet, but I'll stop relying on it for this kind of analysis. And thanks for the article! I'll give that a try.

Comment: I am happy you found some answers